# Windows 10 Calendar doesn't show appointment time correctly

Tags: calendar, windows-10

I imported my Google calendar into my Windows 10 calendar but It doesn't show the appointment time correctly. Here is an example.

There is one-hour time difference.

[image: windows 10 calendar app]

[image: google calendar]

Comment: I'm seeing something similar for appointments I've edited with the Windows 10 Calendar app. It seems to be intermittent behavior, but turning off "Set Time Automatically" in the Date and Time settings and then turning it back on seems to have corrected it (for now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mismatch of your timezone settings between your Google calendar and Windows. Check in your clock settings that your timezone is actually set to the correct one for your location. Then check your timezone settings for Google calendar. Have a look at [this article](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37064?hl=en) for a guide.

Comment: The time zone is the same in the both calender apps.

Comment: And DST settings as well? You say "in both calendar apps". Did you also check the timezone setting of the actual operating system?

Comment: Yes.  I also checked the timezone of OS.

Answer (score 2):

Turning off "Set Time Automatically" in the Date and Time settings and then turning it back on was what worked for me.